# I need to sort a list of 3 numbers from lowest to highest, using a nested loop. Python

Tags: python

I have an assignment for a function in Python, using parameters in a function and giving the function 3 numbers to sort from lowest to highest. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, and I cannot wrap my head around why. Any light shed on this would help me. Thank you. I should be able to change Max(a,b,c) to run any numbers and produce (1,2,3).

```
def Max(a,b,c):
    while a < b:
        if b < c:
            print(a,b,c)
            return
        else:
            print(a,c,b)
            return
    while b < c:
        if c < a:
            print(b,a,c)
            return
        else:
            print(b,c,a)
            return
    while c < a:
        if a < b:
             print(c,a,b)
             return
        else:
             print(c,b,a)
             return

Max(3,1,2)
```

Comment: What are you returning? `return` will break out of the function and none of the other `while` looks will run.

Comment: In what cases it fails and in what it succeds?

Comment: Apologize for not posting my returning value. It depends on the number arrangement, but in the case of  (3,1,2). I'm return (1,3,2). In the case of Max(3,2,1) i'm returning (1,2,3) (which means it kinda works. But not for all cases).  When doing Max(2,3,1)  I'm returning (2,1,3)

Comment: ``I need to sort a list of ...`` there are no lists in your code.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the `while` looks are for because you're not modifying anything on each iteration.

Comment: If `c < a < b`, then your program will return `a, c, b`.  Your top-level comparisons are insufficient to determine the smallest number.

Comment: Again, my mistake. I didn't mean a list as in x = [1,2,3]. Just a print that came out with the sequence of numbers from least to greatest. Still learning terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain comparison operators, so you could just check for each configuration independantly:

```
def Max(a, b, c):
    if a <= b <= c:
        print(a, b, c)
    elif a <= c < = b:
        print(a, c, b)
    elif b <= c < = a:
        print(b, c, a)
    elif b <= a < = c:
        print(b, c, a)
    elif c <= a < = b:
        print(c, a, b)
    else:
        print(c, b, a)
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick Haugh. I didn't think to use the <= and what I assume is else-if ? This worked flawlessly and I'll take a good lesson from it. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Max(a,b,c):
    return sorted([a,b,c])[-1]
```

Two lines, without any loops. Anything shorter than that is not a function.

Also `return max([a,b,c])` would work, but I understand you want to sort the numbers for some reasons

EDIT: your function is called `Max`, but after re-reading your post it looks like you do not want to return only the max values, but all of them sorted in ascending order. If this is the case, remove `[-1]` from the second line in the code above, and change the name of the function to avoid confusion.

Even better, do not create a function to perform a task for which a function made by the developers of python already exists. Just use `sorted()` on a list of your elements in the main code: this is the pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Daniel, I haven't learned sorted in class yet. But will do my best to keep it in my internal archive.  Appreciate your help.